# Android Bluetooth Connection Broken

Tags: android, bluetooth

This is my code

```
package com.bluetouth.con.toconnect;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter; import
android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice; import
android.content.BroadcastReceiver; import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent; import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle; import
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem; import android.view.View; import
android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import android.widget.Button; import
android.widget.ListView; import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.HashMap; import java.util.Set;

public class ConnectActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
View.OnClickListener {

    ListView maListViewPerso;
    Button btn4;
    //On déclare la HashMap qui contiendra les informations pour un item
    HashMap<String, String> map;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> devices;

    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        maListViewPerso = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView01);
        btn4 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button4);

        btn4.setOnClickListener(this);

        btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ConnectActivity.this, R.layout.affichageitem);
        maListViewPerso.setAdapter(btArrayAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_connect, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver bluetoothReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Toast.makeText(ConnectActivity.this, "New Device = " + device.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                btArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button4)
        {
            btArrayAdapter.clear();
            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            Toast.makeText(ConnectActivity.this, "Scanning Devices", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, filter);
            registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        }
    }

}
```

This code always breaks  when I add this line:

```
btArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
btArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Post the exact error

Comment: In my smartphone i get this: L'application <<name>> s'est arrêtée.

Comment: i follow this tutorial: https://sites.google.com/site/installationtutorial/computinglabware/module-5/2-lab-activity/lab1-application-layer/bluetooth/bluetooth-scanner

Answer (score 0):

if i delete this two lines:

> btArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
>                   btArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

my code work and i get a Toast with nom of all devices found